# Patrón \ leyendo datos desde el teclado con Scanner

Tags: java

quiero leer del teclado una fecha con este formato:
dd\mm\aaaa

Lo estoy haciendo así:

```
public class Ejercicio2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        try {
            String datos_entrada = in.readLine();
            Scanner leer = new Scanner(datos_entrada);
            //leer.useDelimiter("\\"); da error
            while (leer.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(leer.nextInt());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

no se que poner en el useDelimiter para que coja de separado el backslash .

Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Usa `Pattern.quote("\\")` dentro de `useDelimiter()`

```
public class Ejercicio2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            try {
                String datos_entrada = in.readLine();
                Scanner leer = new Scanner(datos_entrada);
                leer.useDelimiter(Pattern.quote("\\"));
                while (leer.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(leer.nextInt());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```